# ngTemplateOutlet doesn't seem to work with mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I'm trying to project content into a expanded row but no success so far.
The same approach works everywhere else not sure why its not working with `mat-table`

```
<!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{element.description}}aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
          <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia 
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]='rowDetail'></ng-container></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

And in the usage I tried

```
<demo-table 
[rowDetail]="rowDetailContent "
></demo-table>

<ng-template #rowDetailContent >
This is a passed template
</ng-template>
```

and this

```
<demo-table 
[rowDetail]="details "
></demo-table>
```

`TS`

```
@ViewChild('rowDetailContent') details :TemplateRef<any>;
```

None of them seem to work out.

Here's the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krxt33?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `AppModule`

```
entryComponents: [TableExpandableRowsExample,TableDemoComponent,RowDetailContent],
declarations: [TableDemoComponent,TableExpandableRowsExample,RowDetailContent],
bootstrap: [TableExpandableRowsExample,TableDemoComponent,RowDetailContent],
```

i suspect you don't know what is the purpose of these options.

Try removing `TableDemoComponent` and `RowDetailContent` from `bootstrap` option, so it should be:

```
bootstrap: [TableExpandableRowsExample]
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krxt33-fwqsfe?file=main.ts)**

Comment: Here's some documentation on what the properties actually mean here: https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping